# What can *.itc files contain when not PNG or JPG?

Tags: itunes

Yesterday I was a bit curious what iTunes `.itc` (by default in `~/Music/iTunes/Album Artwork`) files were.

After a bit of research, I made [a script to convert .itc to images (JPG & PNG)](https://github.com/kyro38/MiscStuff/tree/master/Useless/itc/itcToImage.sh).

For 1913 itc files : I get 467 png & 636 jpg files.

I was wondering what the other itc could be. Any idea ?

Comment: Just a guess, but you tried TIFF and GIF? Cool script btw! [This script](http://www.sffjunkie.co.uk/python-itc.html) says ARGB which exports to PNG?

Comment: Nice script, i'll dig into it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well thanks @beroe for the link.

After some digging I wrote a [little documentation of `.itc` files](https://github.com/kyro38/MiscStuff/blob/master/Useless/itc/itcDoc.md).

`.itc` files are actually wrapper of images that are either PNG, JPG or ARGB raw files. `.itc` files can hold multiple images with different size. Most of the time there are 3 images of (128*128, 256*256 & 400*400).

I wrote [a little bash script](https://github.com/kyro38/MiscStuff/blob/master/Useless/itc/itcToImageV2.sh) that convert all `.itc` files into jpg or png and puts them in `~/Music/iTunes/Album Artwork/Images`.

Comment: It sounds like a disk version of Apple's NSImage class, so it can probably contain more image representations than you listed.